# seq to vec conversion - Key must be integer

Tags: clojure

I want to get the indices of nil elements in a vector eg.
[1 nil 3 nil nil 4 3 nil] => [1 3 4 7]

```clj
(defn nil-indices [vec]
  (vec (remove nil? (map
    #(if (= (second %) nil) (first %))
      (partition-all 2 (interleave (range (count vec)) vec)))))
  )
```

Running this code results in

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key must be integer
>   (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

If I leave out the (vec) call surrounding everything, it seems to work, but returns a sequence instead of a vector.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```clj
(defn nil-indices [v]
  (vec (remove nil? (map
    #(if (= (second %) nil) (first %))
      (partition-all 2 (interleave (range (count v)) v))))))
```

Clojure is a LISP-1: It has a single namespace for both functions and data, so when you called `(vec ...)`, you were trying to pass your result sequence *to your data* as a parameter, not to the standard-library vec function.

Comment: damn, how could I miss that :D

Comment: I assumed you were coming from a LISP-2 background; it's a rather contentious split. :)

Answer (score 1):

See other answer for your problem (you are shadowing `vec`), but consider using a simpler approach.

`map` can take multiple arguments, in which case they are passed as additional arguments to the map function, e.g. `(map f c1 c2 ...)` calls `(f (first c1) (first c2) ...)` etc, until one of the sequence arguments is exhausted.

This means your `(partition-all 2 (interleave ...))` is a very verbose way of saying `(map list (range) v)`. There is also a function `map-indexed` which does the same thing. However, it only takes one sequence argument, so `(map-indexed f c1 c2)` is not legal.

Here is your function rewritten for clarity using `map-indexed`, threading, and `nil?`:

```clj
(defn nil-indices [v]
  ; Note: map fn called like (f range-item v-item)
  ;       Not like (f (range-item v-item)) as in your code.
  (->> (map-indexed #(when (nil? %2) %1) v) ;; like (map #(when ...) (range) v)
       (remove nil?)
       vec))
```

However, you can do this instead with reduction and the `reduce-kv` function. This function is like `reduce`, except the reduction function receives three arguments instead of two: the accumulator, the *key* of the item in the collection (index for vectors, key for maps), and the item itself. Using `reduce-kv` you can rewrite this function even more clearly (and it will probably run faster, especially with transients):

```clj
(defn nil-indices [v]
  (reduce-kv #(if (nil? %3) (conj %1 %2) %1) [] v))
```

Comment: You can use `map-indexed` in first example to omit `(range)`: `(map-indexed #(when (nil? %2) %1) v)`

Comment: A few suggestions:  1. If the function is worth defining, make the filtering predicate - here `nil?` - an argument. 2. In your first solution, leave the final `vec` to the caller, retaining laziness for potentially large, even infinite, sequence arguments. 3. It is maybe tidier with the `map-indexed` subject to the `->>`. Thus:
`(defn index-filter [pred coll]
  (->> coll
       (map-indexed #(when (pred %2) %1))
       (remove nil?)))`

For example, 
`(index-filter nil? [nil 1 2 nil 4 nil nil])
=> (0 3 5 6)`